# How do you write to a Firebase Database using AFHTTPSessionManager?

Tags: objective-c, macos, rest, firebase, afnetworking

I am attempting to write an macOS data entry app to manipulate a Firebase Database (which is powering an iOS app).

I am able to read from the database using the code:

```
    NSString *urlString = @"https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/Object.json";
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"orderBy" : @"\"updatedAt\"",
                                 @"startAt" : @"0",
                                 @"auth" : authString
                                 };

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    [manager GET:urlString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

However I can't get writes to work. To trouble shoot I have set both the `read` and `write` rules in my Firebase Database to `true` and am just trying to write anything to the database. For example:

```
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *objectDictionary = @{@"first" : @"Foo", @"last" : @"Bar"};
    NSData *objectData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:objectDictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSString *urlString2 = @"https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/Object2.json"
    [manager PUT:urlString2 parameters:objectData success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"responseObject %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"- error %ld - %@",(long)task.state,error);
    }];
```

I have experimented with having the PUT parameters be a NSDictionary, NSString, and NSData. Each time I end up with the same error: `Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)"`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I figured out a way to write using `AFHTTPSessionManager`'s `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` method, but I am still interested in why the `PUT:parameters:success:failure:` method doesn't work.